How to use Drawer and Tab Navigation with seperate Routes in Expo Router with File-Based Routing
i'm using Expo Router with file-based Routing. I want to create a drawer with only the option to show to page3 and a tab navigation to swtich between page1 and page2.
Best case would be to just push the page3 on top of all screens and just give a backbutton in the left side of the header and not show the drawer icon on page3
I don't know how to do this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
